# Android: Change focus order in XML when field visibility changes to GONE

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout that contains several edit texts (name, phone, comments).  Before the view is shown, one edit text is hidden (comments.setVisibility(View.GONE)) or visible based on the results from an HTTP call.  If that view is hidden and the user tab's from the previous view, then the program halts.

In Winforms, if a field is hidden then the next item in the tab order is focused.  Is there some way to do this in the XML for my view in Android?

I could just change the next focus down and next focus up programmatic-ally, but that seems like something that should be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any way that Android does this.  So here's a method to set the next focus down assuming your views form a loop through next focus down:

```
protected int getNextFocusDownBasedOnVisibility(View view)
{
    int nextViewDownId = View.NO_ID;

    if (view.getVisibility() != View.GONE)
    {
        boolean keepGoing = true;
        View nextView = view;

        while (keepGoing)
        {
            keepGoing = false;
            nextViewDownId = nextView.getNextFocusDownId();

            if (nextViewDownId != View.NO_ID)
            {
                nextView = findViewById(nextViewDownId);

                if (nextView.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                {
                    keepGoing = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return nextViewDownId;
}
```